# MouseEvent.offsetX/Y resets to 0 if moving over different child elements

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Take the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3Lmvrc0/).

It contains a parent div with 3 child divs. A click-listener is attached to the parent div and should throw alerts with the mouse position relative to the parent div:

```
const parent = document.getElementById('main');
parent.addEventListener('click', handleMouseClick);

function handleMouseClick(e) {
    alert(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
```

What I expect: Click on any of the child divs and get the click position relative to the parent div (#main).

What actually happens: OffsetX/Y always equals the click position relative to the child I clicked on.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it? Is there another way to get the mouse position relative to the parent div, taking potential scrolling into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want like this:

```
function handleMouseClick(e) {
  child = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    alert(e.offsetX+child.left, e.offsetY+child.top);
}
```

The event is triggered for the child because it is on top. So you can grab the child's getBoundingClientRect() and you can access it's left and top fields to determine where it is in relation to its parent. I hope that helps!

Edit: If the parent of the event.target is not positioned at (0:0) then you will also have to involve the offset of the parent (and possibly the parent's parent and so on) in order to get the position of the mouse click. You can traverse the parents of DOM objects by calling on the parentElement field (e.target.parentElement).

for example:

```
function handleMouseClick(e) {
  childBounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  parentBounds = e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
   alert((e.offsetX+childBounds.left-parentBounds.left) + ", "+ (e.offsetY+childBounds.top-parentBounds.top));
}
```

Comment: Correction, it does not work if the target of the listener itself is not positioned at (0;0). I had to subtract the parent rect's position to make it work: `alert(\`${e.offsetX+child.left-parentRect.left} ${e.offsetY+child.top-parentRect.top}\`);`. If you add that to your answer I'll re-accept it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a css attribute to child element

```
.child {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

take the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/ldd/full/oNXLjLB)

Comment: You're a genius!

Answer (score -2):

```
SensorGoldenCalTable:{   // SensorGoldenCalTable
       PixId:    3,
       SlimLscType:    0,
       Width:    0,
       Height:    0,
       OffsetX:    0,
       OffsetY:    0,
       TblSize:    0,
       IspLSCReg:    {0, 0xd048d035, 0, 0x00480041, 0},
       GainTable:    {

            0x99, 0x6d, 0x94, 0x63, 0xa1, 0x62, 0x8b, 0x5f, 0x1a, 0x5d, 0xb2, 0x54, 0xf2, 0x53, 0xba, 0x51, 
            0x0c, 0x4f, 0x59, 0x48, 0x73, 0x47, 0xba, 0x45, 0xa7, 0x45, 0xee, 0x3f, 0xec, 0x3e, 0x7a, 0x3d, 
            0xcb, 0x3e, 0x03, 0x3a, 0x04, 0x39, 0xd4, 0x37, 0x23, 0x3a, 0xf5, 0x35, 0x09, 0x35, 0x0c, 0x34, 
            0x69, 0x37, 0xac, 0x33, 0xc0, 0x32, 0xde, 0x31, 0x8d, 0x36, 0x0b, 0x33, 0x10, 0x32, 0x5a, 0x31, 
            0x85, 0x37, 0xc4, 0x33, 0xd1, 0x32, 0x24, 0x32, 0x2a, 0x3a, 0xfa, 0x35, 0x0f, 0x35, 0x30, 0x34, 
            0x02, 0x3f, 0xce, 0x39, 0xe8, 0x38, 0x93, 0x37, 0xb8, 0x45, 0xfd, 0x3f, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0x98, 0x3d, 
            0x25, 0x50, 0xd6, 0x48, 0x16, 0x48, 0x4a, 0x46, 0x17, 0x5e, 0x7f, 0x55, 0xd1, 0x54, 0x48, 0x52,
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: How does this answer help in any way?